# Match all pattent in regex - java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find method calls in Java source code.

Here is my current attempt:

> Subject:
>
> ```
> exec.execute(new EngineRobot(robotPool));
> ```
>
> Pattern:
>
> ```
> ((?!while|if|for\b)\b\w+)\s*\((.*)\)
> ```
>
> [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ4oV7/1)

I want to find both method names ("execute" and "EngineRobot") but it only returns "execute".

Comment: fetch the second group.

Comment: Is there a reason for that? Why would it use one set of parentheses instead of the other? Your question makes it seem somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: Thankyou. But there any other way to find in fist group or not ?

Comment: The other? I just imagine this way to detect method call

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to match *both* of the words using one regex. Just use a lookahead for that so that the regex doesn't consume too many characters.

```
((?!while|if|for\b)\b\w+)\s*(?=\((.*)\))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ4oV7/4)

Comment: Yes, you are my hero :)